# How to take Web view Data As UIImage in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have QA Code for user depends on name,Id in Web View.
Now I want to get the web view QA Code as in Image View(Or UIImage) I tried like this,

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(webview.bounds.size);
[webview.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

But I got the web view frame only,but not showing content(QA Code Image). Please give me the suggestion. Thanks

Comment: you are taking the snapshot of the entire uiwebview. since thats the bounds you are passing when you are creating the `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` context. can you add more  details...

Comment: I had taken one more image view and i tried that get the image in image view.But it not shows correctly.